# React: added product changes it's attributes after I add another product with different attribute while on the same product page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, arrays

So let's say you are on the product page of a Nike T-shirt, you choose the color and size(eg:black and S) and add it to cart. Now the cart contains 1 Nike T-SHIRT with selectedAttributes: color: black, size: s. Now, while on the same T-shirt page, you choose color white and size M, the previous added T-shirt's attributes change from (color:black into color: white, and form size:s into size:M) and now you have in cart 2 T-SHIRTS SIZE :M AND COLOR: BLACK. What am I doing wrong?

```
class PDP extends Component {
      state = {
        currentProduct: this.props.location.state,
        selectState: [],
        testObj: {},
      } 
    render() {
    let product = this.state.currentProduct;
    let handleChange = (evt,attribute) => {
            const test = Object.assign({}, product);
            this.state.testObj[attribute] = evt.target.value;
            this.state.selectState.push(this.state.testObj);
            let selectedAttributes = [...new Set(this.state.selectState)];
            test.selectedAttributes = selectedAttributes;
            this.setState((state) => ({
              currentProduct: test
            }))
          } 
    
    <button className="addToCart" onClick={() => this.props.data.addProduct(this.state.currentProduct)}>ADD TO CART</button>
    
     addProduct = (product) => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          cart: state.cart.concat(product),
        }))
       
      }
```

Comment: What are `selectState` and `testObj` for?

Comment: select state is an array of objects where I store the selected proprieties(testobj)

Comment: Can't figure it out from the code above. I'm sure you will get better help if you create a working sample of your code.

Comment: you mean a screen recording ?

Comment: just added a demo: https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/726596880, please help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

Its not quiet clear form the code you have posted, still it seems to be an issue with cloning of the product object in handleChange function.

Instead of using `Object.assign` try the code below just for the sake of testing the issue.

`const test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));`

Comment: tried as you said , same result :D

Comment: Do the same for selectedAttributes as well i.e. deep cloning

Comment: I don't know if I did the deep cloning well since it's the first time I heard of it, here's the result: https://imgur.com/a/Nm1RkRJ, check it up when you have time

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```js
this.state.testObj[attribute] = evt.target.value;
```

As objects are passed be reference, changing any attribute in `testObj` (say the color) changes the color for all the other passed references.

try

```js
let handleChange = (evt, attribute) => {
  const test = Object.assign({}, product);
  this.state.testObj[attribute] = evt.target.value;
  const testObj = Object.assign({}, this.state.testObj);
  this.state.selectState.push(testObj);
  let selectedAttributes = [...new Set(this.state.selectState)];
  test.selectedAttributes = selectedAttributes;
  this.setState((state) => ({
    currentProduct: test,
  }));
};
```

Comment: Now none of the attributes are displayed(empty objects are pushed into the selectedAtributes array) https://imgur.com/a/v3uAFH1

Comment: I added a full `handleChange` example. Check if it works and let me know

Comment: tested and this is the result : https://imgur.com/a/jhy2c9j

Comment: i cropped too much from the bottom , it has the same attributes as the first product (capacity: 512g)

Comment: Is it on GitHub? I would like to give it a try

Comment: haven't uploaded it since is my first react project and it's such a mess